# How do I get a space between my pork filling and the hot water raised crust?

Tags: pork, pie

I tried to make a hand raised pork pie and made the jelly from pigs' trotters and bones but when I tried to pour it down the hole it seems there is no space between the filling and the crust. How do i get that space?

Comment: Did you pour when the pies were hot or cold?

Comment: Did you cook the pies before pouring?

Comment: I cooked the pies and left them to go cold then put them in the fridge to go completely cold before pouring in the jelly.

Comment: The space arises when the pork filling shrinks as it cooks, leaving the crust behind. Check your filling recipe and check you have cooked it well - that’s all I can suggest.  Did the crust collapse onto the pork perhaps as it cooked?